# Extracting one numeric value that matches preceding text regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a specific numeric value (can be between 1 and 7 digits) that is preceded by one fixed keyword, but there might be some characters in between that I want to ignore (as well as the preceding keyword).

The string is a parsed email header and can look something like this:

```
To: tesrecipient <test@test.com>
Subject: RE: Re:(ejTag: 24) Testemail
Thread-Topic: Re:(ejTag: 24) Testemail
Thread-Index: AQHTrH7+kcQ/Afcr+ECnKm9qEjGKtKOxpzfg
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 09:27:15 +0100
Message-ID: <c64332ea7c9d4fa8882748fdf152bc7e@test.com>
References: <9f8eb2fd5031498eb29443ca9ba20b91@test.com>
<!251534C4C-20-V2@domain.test.com>
In-Reply-To: <!251534C4C-20-V2@domain.test.com>
Accept-Language: nb-NO, en-US
```

What I want out of this is the numeric value after `ejTag` in the `Thread-Topic` part of the string, in this case 24.
My current regex matches only if `ejTag` is not preceded by anything between `ejTag` and `Thread-Topic`.

```
(?<=Thread-Topic: \(ejTag:)(.*[0-9])
```

I want to ignore the possible `re:` characters that a email subject can contain between `Thread-Topic` and `ejTag`, while only capturing the numeric value after `ejTag:`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this what you want? (?<=Thread-Topic:).*\(ejTag:\s*(s*w*[0-9]+)\)

Comment: With PCRE, you may use [`(?m)^Thread-Topic:.*\(ejTag:\s*\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/VAZRvw/1)

Comment: You can try `(?<=Thread-Topic: Re:\(ejTag: )([0-9]{1,7})` https://regex101.com/r/Y6QEHH/1/

Comment: Please add the programming language tag to the question to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
(?<=Thread-Topic: Re:\(ejTag: )([0-9]{1,7})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6QEHH/1/)

I've added `Re:` and limited number repetition.

EDIT

For optional `Re:` you need to have two subpatterns with alternative (`(Re:)?` won't work, because lookbehind needs to have constant width).

```
(?<=Thread-Topic: Re:\(ejTag: )([0-9]{1,7})|(?<=Thread-Topic: \(ejTag: )([0-9]{1,7})
```

[Updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6QEHH/2/)